# SPGridView filtering (Empty) option not coming for empty data

Tags: sharepoint

I have displayed my SharePoint list data in a SPGridView. I have also applied sorting, filtering & paging to the same. All are working fine except the SPGridView filtering is not showing (Empty) option for empty data. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, when filtering in a SPGridView doesn't work the way you want.. it is very complicated to change. If you're serious about doing this... take a look at creating a new class inheriting from SPGridView and overriding `GetCallbackResult`.